# Using a parameter of type Type for casting

Tags: c#, .net, casting

How can I cast a object obtained by deserialization into a type that is specified as the method parameter

```
public Base GetDerived(MemoryStream stream, Type type)
{
   var obj = deserialzer.Deserialize(stream)  ;
   // return obj as type
}
```

where:

```
Class Derived: Base {}
```

and type argument would be `typeof(Derived)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of passing it is as a parameter, you can do the following

```
public T GetDerived<T>(MemoryStream stream) where T : Base
{
   var obj = (T)deserialzer.Deserialize(stream);
   // return obj as type
}
```

called via

```
var serialized = obj.GetDerived<MyClass>(stream);
```

You can read more about generic methods [on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)